# Plot Symmetric Triangle on a Stock chart created using MplFinance Animation

Tags: python, mplfinance

[image: graph example]

I have to create a plot like above on the live candle stick plot I have created. And it also needs to be updated in real-time as the news candles are formed. Can anyone help me out here?
I have already tried the `tlines` parameter of `mplfinance`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The first step is to be able to make the plot you want ***without*** live updates (aka animation).  Are you able to do that?  It is not clear from your question whether you are able to draw the trend lines you want, but are just having issues with real-time updates, or whether you simply cannot get the trend lines the way you want them at all.  Please clarify.  And please show completely whatever code you have already tried, and what the result of that code was.